# Incorrect output from LM324N opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, analog, esp32

I've build a **peak detector** with an **LM324 operational amplifier** having a piezo contact microphone as input.

[image: peak detector schematic]

The power voltage is ~5V.

Even though the voltage on pin 12 (piezo in) is approximately 0V, the output of the opamp (pin 14) is around 4V.  I am measuring **before** the diode (i.e. directly on the IC pin)!  The input on pin 13 is also around 4V.

The measurements of the other opamps are as expected.

I first thought, that I must have a bad IC (damaged during soldering,...).  Unfortunately another attempt on a second board led to the same misbehavior.

Here is the complete schematics of the whole project.  (The final board will run on 4V.  In my tests until now I have however always used 5V instead).
[image: schematics]

Is there anything wrong with my circuit?  Do you have an idea, which would explain this behavior?

Here is the view of the PCB:

[image: pcb front]
[image: pcb back]

---

Note about the above schematic:

I have already fixed the `power ctrl` pin.  Any other suggestions are welcome.
This is the current revision.
[image: complete schematics fixed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Op-amp inputs need resistance to 0 volts to prevent internal bias currents raising the pins to a silly voltage. You don't appear to have used any bias/discharge resistor. Try 100 kohm from `piezo in` to `0 volts`. A piezo device is capacitive and will not perform this biasing/discharge function.

[image]

Comment: The microphone is connected with the Mik_conn_01x02_pin J6 connector, and has GND on one side (Pin 1 of J6) and "outputs" on `piezo_in` (Pin 2 of J6).

The J7 is only used for testing.

Comment: What is the relevance of that point. If the mike is a piezo it won't make any difference because a piezo is a capacitor in nature.

Comment: thanks.  I hadn't realized that and my next revision will add a resistor to GND.  It however doesn't cure the problem.  I measured the `piezo_in` at around 0V.

Maybe my voltmeter was "discharging" the `piezo_in` pin.  I will investigate..

Comment: @close2 A multimeter is essentially a 10 MΩ resistor (some models 1 MΩ, others might be 100 MΩ), which will be enough to discharge the tiny parasitic capacitance fairly quickly.